# How to implement previous next day buttons to change the date in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datepicker, nsdate, nsdateformatter

[image: Screenshot Provided]

As shown in the above page I have a date (current date by default) on a label. In the format of MM dd.

I have two buttons to change the date next day & the previous day.

How should I implement change the date by using these buttons?

Any tutorial / advice (I don't think there is any involvement of datepicker in this)

Answer (score 1):

Use these two functions to get previous date and next date and then use the returned date and use only month and year to display on your label.

```
+ (NSDate *) getDate:(NSDate *)fromDate daysAgo:(NSUInteger)days
{
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dateComponents.day = -1*days;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *previousDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                                                     toDate:fromDate
                                                    options:0];
    [dateComponents release];
    return previousDate;
}

+ (NSDate *) getDate:(NSDate *)fromDate daysAhead:(NSUInteger)days
{
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dateComponents.day = days;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *previousDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                                                     toDate:fromDate
                                                    options:0];
    [dateComponents release];
    return previousDate;
}
```

Comment: Nice memory leak in both methods ... you are not releasing your dateComponents instance. By the way, one method should be enough by using a signed days parameter.

Comment: yeah, if you are using ARC then no memory leaks are there bro :)

Comment: Of course, but I don't think that good pattern to rely on compiler parameter for proper memory handling, or at least this should be part of your feedback. Anyway I don't want to argue here .. we all know that ARC is so BAD :)

Comment: increment/decrement date only at first click next there is no incremetn in hte date

Comment: you need to set the from date every time after decrement or increment of the day. As the function return a date use it as from date for the next time it should work

Answer (score -1):

Try these methods

```
- (NSDate *) dateByAddingDays: (int) dDays : (NSDate*)presntdate
{
NSTimeInterval aTimeInterval = [presntdate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 86400 * dDays;
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:aTimeInterval];
return newDate;
}

- (NSDate *) dateBySubtractingDays: (int) dDays : (NSDate*)presntdate
{
return [self dateByAddingDays: dDays*-1 :presntdate];
}
```

Comment: A day can have more or less than 24 hours, if clocks are adjusted for daylight savings time.

Comment: increment/decrement date only at first click next there is no incremetn in hte date